# how convert double to string

Tags: java, android, types

```
public String solve() {
        ss = log(pow(y, -sqrt(abs(x)))) * (x + y / 2) + sin(atan(z));
        result = toString(ss);
        return result;
    }
```

Don't get how do I convert `ss` to string. I neen return result in String format

Comment: `return String.valueOf(ss)`

Comment: tnx a lot! that's helped me

Comment: 3rd variant: result =  "" + ss; (works with primitives)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply concatenate it with an empty String which converts it automatically:

```
String stringFromDouble = ss + "";
```

Alternatives:

```
 String stringFromDouble = Double.toString(ss);
 String stringFromDouble = String.valueOf(ss)
 String stringFromDouble = new Double(ss).toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, you can do this:

```
result = Double.toString(ss);
```

However, there are at least two problems here:

1. Your `solve()` function is attempting to do two unrelated tasks: a) find the solution of some mathematical equation and b) format the solution into a human readable format. By the functions name, I think it should only do the first thing and another function should do the second.
2. Using `Double.toString()` leaves a lot of room for variation. This is primarily due to the nature of how a computer represents a decimal number as a `double`. This is beyond the scope of this answer, but I suggest you read [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for more details. To provide more control over the exact format, you should use [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) instead.

**Aside:**

I see that you do not declare `result` or `ss` in the code you posted here. If you are declaring these as class fields such as `private double ss;`, I suggest that you declare them as local variables instead. In general, you should declare variables in the narrowest scope possible.